# How to get UISlider to step in decimals

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, stringwithformat

I have a UISlider with a min - 0.1 & max - 1. I want the label displaying the value to display the decimals and not just 0 and 1.

Here is the current code:

```
- (IBAction)sliderChange:(UISlider *)sender { // When the slider for the power factor is moved
sender.minimumValue = 0.1;
sender.maximumValue = 1.0;
int progress = lround(sender.value);
self.sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", progress];
```

}

Please if any one can help I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Just remove this line, 

int progress = around(sender.value);
this makes the decimal to integer.

directly use as :
self.sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", sender.value];//By Default slider returns float value.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: your `progress` variable is an int. Change it to `CGFloat`.

Next, try using

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", progress]
```

instead (notice the `%f` instead of `%d`). `%f` is for floating-point values and `%d` is for integers.

And here's the official [[NSString stringWithFormat] formatting docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Comment: He is still rounding the value and casting it down to int